# New column addition in SQL query to display whether the record contains child element or not

Tags: sql, oracle, siebel

The requirement is to display activity records (S_EVT_ACT table) along with a new column in it to display whether the activity record contains any attachments or not.
Activity attachments belongs to S_ACTIVTY_ATT table and has relationship with parent activity as attachment's PAR_ROW_ID = activity's ROW_ID.

The new column can either display output as Y or N for each activity record. Also, the new column can either display the count of attachments for an activity.

what should be the SQL query in this case.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1):

Use `exists`:

```
select a.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from S_ACTIVTY_ATT att
                          where att.PAR_ROW_ID = a.ROW_ID
                         )
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as has_attachment
from S_EVT_ACT a;
```

In general, `exists` performs better than any solution with aggregation.  In particular, with an index on `att(PAR_ROW_ID)` this should be quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to have a column, you have to populate (increase) the value each time you insert an attachment. If you only want to see it in an SELECT-Query, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT act.*, att.ATT_COUNT 
FROM S_EVT_ACT act
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT PAR_ROW_ID, COUNT(*) AS ATT_COUNT
        FROM S_ACTIVTY_ATT 
        GROUP BY PAR_ROW_ID ) AS att ON (act.ROW_ID = att.PAR_ROW_ID)
```

Notice: it should work, but depending on your number of rows and other things i don't know there could be better solutions.